# what is the command in GDB to step into the next function in the flow?

Tags: gdb

I am running GDB. I donot wish to use "s" command and step into the next line.
I directly want to jump to the starting line of the next function in the code flow.
And I havent put any breakpoint ( because I dont know which is the next function to be hit ).
Is there any command to do so ?

### Edit:

Sorry. I did not ask my question clearly.
I will give 1 example.

```
line#1      int function(int a)
line#2      {
line#3        int b;
line#4        b = 10;
line#5        b = b + a;
......        ...
......        ...
......        ...
......        ...
......        ...
......        ...
......        ...
......        ...
......        ...
......        ...
......        ...
......        ...
line#1000     if (10 == b)
line#1001     {
line#1002        func1(); 
line#1003     } else
line#1004     {
line#1005        func2(); 
line#1006     }
line#1007   } // function(int a);
......        ...
......        ...
......        ...
line#2000   void func1()
line#2001   {
line#2002      printf("hello\n");
line#2003   }
line#2004   void func2()
line#2005   {
line#2006      printf("hi\n");
line#2007   }
```

Now, my control is currently at line#4.
I donot know if func1 will be called, or func2 will be called.
I have not put any breakpoint in func1 or func2.
Since function() is a big function, I donot want to use "step" command to reach either func1 or func2.
In this case, consider value of "a" is 0. 
Hence func1() will be called.
Is there any command to directly jump from line#4 to line#2000 without putting any breakpoint ?
So, any command to directly jump to next function to be hit in the code flow ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your program sets up the frame base pointer `$bp` upon entry to a function, you can simply `watch` it, then `continue`, and execution will stop just after entry to another function. (This will also stop execution when a function returns.)

Note that some compilers don't emit code that uses a frame base pointer at all, and some may choose not to update the pointer in functions in which there aren't any local variables.

```
$ gdb -q args
(gdb) list
1   main(int argc, char **argv)
2   {
3       for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)
4           printf("arg %d is %s\n", i, argv[i]);
5   }
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdfa8) at args.c:3
3       for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)
(gdb) watch $bp
Watchpoint 2: $bp
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Watchpoint 2: $bp

Old value = -8608
New value = -8880
0x0000000000453e24 in vfprintf ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000453e24 in vfprintf ()
#1  0x000000000040f3d6 in printf ()
#2  0x00000000004009f1 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdfa8) at args.c:4
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in command to do this in gdb.

If you wanted to implement it, you could probably do so in Python.  The idea would be to record the current frame, then invoke `step` repeatedly until the current frame changes.  At that point you know the inferior has either called a function or returned from the current function.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That will indeed solve my problem!!